# Arithmetic Remainder Problem

Tags: arithmetic

"What is the remainder when 582 is divided by 3?"

I want to know how can I solve questions like the one displayed in the image above whether they have a remainder or not, quickly and without the use of a calculator, with paper drafts and without them.

I am not very sharp in mathematics so I would be very grateful if someone could elaborate with me on issues like these.

Comment: There's a famous criterion to determine whether a number is divisible by $3$. Are you aware of it?

Comment: Actually this task is so easy that you can directly solve check it. Note that $582 = 300 + 270 + 12$. What is the remainder of each term?

Comment: @Kman3 No I am not familiar with this criterion, could you please share it with me?

Comment: Questions "like the one displayed" depend a lot on the divisor. For the divisor $3$ and $9$ the remainder is easily calculated, use the sum of the digits instead. So the remainder in "$582$ divided by $3$" is the same one as in "$5+8+2$ divided by $3$" - and the latter my be simpler... For other "simple divisors" like $2$, $4$, $5$, $8$, $11$ there are more or less easy rules to get the remainder... For $7$ or for $13$ things are not so simple to visualize...

Comment: @MachineLearner Are you a wizard? that's pretty clever.

Comment: @MichaelVainshtein As mentioned by others, if the sum of a number's digits is a multiple of $3$, then the number is divisible by $3$. So I can tell immediately that $582/3$ has remainder zero because $5+8+2=15=5(3)$. One straightforward way you could do these problems is with long division, but if you don't have pen and paper I guess you would have to do long division in your head.

Answer (score 0):

To check divisibility by 3, add the digits of your number. In this case do $5+8+2$ and see if the sum is divisible by 3. If it is, remainder is 0.

For other such rules, see this Wikipedia page: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_rule)